PostgreSQL copy command results in 'replacement characters'
I have a Java application where I run a COPY command. In this command, I copy the query result to stdout in csv format.
COPY (<query>) to stdout (format csv).

In some of the columns, I have unicode characters, which, once I read the csv file, are represented as replacement characters (�).
How can I prevent this behavior?

Set the proper encoding.

Why, btw, is a Java app allowing the output to go to stdout instead of processing that output in the app?

That's not Java code. If you are making a question about Java code then share it. The issue could be between the SQL statement and the Java code. Also provide the table definition and examples of data in the table and in the output. Basically a [mre].

You're using different encodings. Check the database, check your code, and make a choice what to use for both.

@AdrianKlaver to what?

@g00se just some custom logic that has been decided to be that way.

So it goes to stdout then you redirect it to x.csv in the console?

I create a java sql statement of copy sql command, then create PGCopyInputStream(conn, statement), and read it via InputStreamReader.

To whatever the encoding is for wherever you are sending stdout to. Read Server/Client conversion.
